# jQuery superfish adding overflow hidden on ul tags when using box-sizing property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, superfish

I'm having a weird issue with jQuery superfish menu plugin everything is working properly when using `animation: {opacity: 'show'}` and the inline styles applied to `ul` elements are:

`display: none; visibility: hidden;`

I want to use `animation: {height: 'show'}`
but when using it the drop down menu only shows 1st level drop downs because superfish is adding `overflow: hidden;` to the `ul` elements and the inline styles applied are:

`display: none; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;`

so the problem is `overflow: hidden;` which is preventing the nested ul elements to show on hover so I tried adding `overflow: visible !important;` which fixed the issue but the behavior of the menu is sluggish and I don't want this solution.

So I found out that the `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` inside my css file is making this behavior, when removed, superfish doesn't add `overflow: hidden;` to the ul elements.

I created a demo on codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Awqdn

Summary of what's happening:

1- `animation: {opacity: 'show'}` works fine even if I have `* {box-sizing: border-box;}`

2- `animation: {height: 'show'}` doesn't work because of the overflow hidden added to ul elements by the plugin, and this problem is resolved when removing `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` from the css file.

So how can I fix this ? and whats making superfish add `overflow: hidden;` when I have `box-sixing: border-box;` ?

And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` it gives `overflow:hidden` during the animation and removes it after animation ends. But with this line it don't remove overflow after animation. I have found ticket in jQuery tracker http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10335

To resolve this issue you can remove overflow after animation

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#nav').superfish({
    animation: {height:'show'},
    onShow: function(){
      $(this).css("overflow", "visible");
    }
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Apqyl

Comment: @Norris it's no longer needed, it's fixed with the new version get it [here](https://github.com/joeldbirch/superfish)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use the clearfix hack instead of overflow:hidden;

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

Comment: I'm not using overflow hidden, it's the plugin adding it to the elements.

Comment: Peter, you have probably something in your (normalize.)css that triggers this. That is box-sizing: border-box; or a variation.